# iCloud Photos not in sync with Mac

Tags: macos, icloud, photos, catalina

I am using macOS Catalina 10.15.1, after switching on iCloud Photos, now I got about 14975 photos and the syncing has stopped. However, my Mac Photos has 27380 photos.

If trying to switch off iCloud Photos on Mac (to later switch on to force a sync), a pop up dialog will says it will removed 11324 photos from my Mac!

Is it possible to clear the iCloud Photos and start all over again? I can't switch off iCloud Photos without it warning that half the photos will be deleted.

PS: I have set up that the Mac has the original copies.

Comment: The only way to 'clear the iCloud Photos' is turn off iCloud Photos.  The photos will be removed from your Mac but they're retained in iCloud as well as any other device signed into iCloud with the same credentials.  You have a lot of photos so you should keep the Mac logged in, powered on, lid up, and connected to the internet overnight.  It might take a few days to resync the photos.

Comment: But here's the problem - turning off iCloud Photos will wipe out 11324 photos from my Mac (at least this is what the dialog says). And iCloud Photos only have 14975 of the Mac 27380 photos. The number don't really adds up but this is what the iCloud.com and Mac photos said.

Comment: There’s an issue somewhere.  However, you should backup your photos to an external drive first, before you do anything.  Next, do you have any other device signed into iCloud with the same account>. You can use that to verify the photo count and to make sure all your photos are stored correctly.

Comment: Yes I have backup on Mac, last I check is more than 20000 photos. The other devices all got sync from download from iCloud, so they all have the iCloud count. The syncing might have gone wrong during Catalina beta test, so now I am stuck.

Comment: Yes, there is a problem with iCloud photo syncing in the beta releases.  Is this machine currently on the Catalina beta?  Please [edit] your question to add the OS version info.  Some people have resolved this by [creating a new system photo library](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204414).  I'm sure you have an external backup of your photos if you are/were on the beta.

Comment: No, I am already using final 10.15.1. Yes, I have backup the Photos Library on Mac to external devices. The question is I can't switch off iCloud without it trying to delete thousands of photos.